# Simulating macros with return in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macros

In Obj-C, I could define a macro

```
#define check_nil(x) if (!x) { return nil }
```

which can be used to test whether a function has returned `nil` (indicating an error), and if that's the case, the caller can simply return `nil` -- propagating the error up the stack. I am writing a parser, and this pattern happens very often. E.g.

```
- (id)caller {
    ...
    id z = [self callee];
    check_nil(z);
    ...
}

- (id)callee {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, after moving to swift, macros are gone. Function (with `@autoclosure`) are to replace them, but not in this case. Now my code is littered with identical `if` checks.

Any idea to replicate the same thing in Swift?

Comment: Is `if nil == z { return nil }` really worse? To me that is much more clear than your macro that can secretly exit out of the method.

Comment: I am also missing this feature. @drewag It's more to type, and ideally I'd want to be able to use `z` as a constant after the check, as opposed to an optional that needs unwrapping. For now I'm using the common pattern like `if let z = self.callee() { ...` but then I have to indent the whole rest of the function :/

Comment: @pejalo you can always use a guard statement if you don't want to indent the rest of the code

Comment: Thanks @drewag I was unaware of `guard`. It's still a bit verbose with the required `else { return }` after it, but better than indenting IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to implement that pattern exactly.

Perhaps you could use a type that will turn future operations into no-ops if they ever return nil:

```
struct NonNil<T> {
    var cantBeNil: T?

    mutating func update(withClosure: () -> T?) {
        if self.cantBeNil != nil {
            self.cantBeNil = withClosure()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this struct like so:

```
func myFunc() -> String? {
    var nonNil = NonNil(cantBeNil: "")

    nonNil.update {
        // some action
        return "new value"
    }

    nonNil.update {
        // another action that ends up returning nil
        return nil
    }

    // The rest of these don't end up calling the closure
    nonNil.update {
        println("not called")
        return ""
    }

    nonNil.update {
        println("not called")
        return ""
    }

    return nonNil.cantBeNil
}
```

The idea being that if any operation returns nil, the rest of the code will fall through until the return statement, not executing any additional operations.

This will also visually separate all of the parts of the code that can cause the value to be set to nil

Comment: Not exactly what I am after, but pretty interesting solution, appreciate!